# page content "erasing" background

Tags: html, css, background, z-index, background-color

I've run into a troubling situation on an unfortunately simple site.

[live site](http://nevaehstudiodallas.com/about/)

In the section on the right, the entire container should be filled with white. However the page content seems to be erasing - for lack of a better word - the background. I've tried utilizing `z-index`, `background-color`, etc to no avail. Where have I gone wrong?

CSS

```
#container {
    height: 100%;
    width: 980px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#about, #services, #contact {
    background: rgba(246, 246, 246, 0.55) !important;
    float: right;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 100px;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 622px;
    z-index: -5000;
}

.left, .right {
    width: 300px;
}

.left {
    float: left;
    padding-right: 15px;
}

.right {
    float: right;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="about">
<p>Hello. We are __.</p>
<ul class="stylists">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
</ul>
<p>Content ipsum</p>
</div><!-- end #about -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check please your CSS on real site. You're assigned background image to everything:

```
html, body, div, span, object, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, address, code, img, small, strong, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label {
background: url("img/bg.jpg") no-repeat fixed center center / cover transparent;
border: 0 none;
font-size: 100%;
margin: 0;
outline: 0 none;
padding: 0;
vertical-align: baseline;
```

}

Just split it into two rules:

```
html, body, div, span, object, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, address, code, img, small, strong, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label {
border: 0 none;
font-size: 100%;
margin: 0;
outline: 0 none;
padding: 0;
vertical-align: baseline;
}
body {background: url("img/bg.jpg") no-repeat fixed center center / cover transparent;}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're setting the same hair background image on pretty much all the elements on the page, with the following code:

```
/* Reset */

html, body, div, span, object, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, address, code, img,
small, strong, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label {
  background: url(img/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  ...
}
```

Try setting the hair image as background on only the `html` or the `body` or a container `div`.